# regex to replace captured group, want to filter by linestart

Tags: regex, r

(notice the newline before Bob)

```
my_string = "Alice & 1 & a \nBob & 2 & b" 
gsub("(?m)(?<=& )(.+?)","(\\1)", my_string, perl=TRUE)
> "Alice & (1) & (a) \nBob & (2) & (b)"
```

How do I adjust the regex to only parenthesise the entries in the line that starts with Alice?

All variations of `^A` that I've tried either capture Alice itself or only capture the first occurence of the group after Alice.

edit: expected output

```
"Alice & (1) & (a) \nBob & 2 & b"
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: it won't replace `2`

Comment: The OP didn't show the expected output, so it was just a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(*SKIP)(*F)`

```
gsub("^(?!Alice\\b).*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=& )(\\S+)", "(\\1)", s, perl=T)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vS2lU5/2)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting. Thanks for an answer that works flawlessly and thanks even more for introducing me to regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

Now sure how efficient this is, but you can always apply it to a vector containing a separate entry for each line

```
l <- strsplit(my_string, "\n")[[1]]
paste(ifelse(substr(l, 1, 5) == "Alice", gsub("(?<=& )(.+?)(?m)","(\\1)", l, perl=TRUE), l), collapse = "\n")
# [1] "Alice & (1) & (a) \nBob & 2 & b"
```